# Multilingual website, tricks and solutions

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm going to make a multilingual website (3 languages) . I'm curious, are there any ways or rules how to make it properly?  My instrument is Laravel 5.4.

Problems I faced:

1. how to store data in database: in a single table with many rows (one per language), or create a few tables (one per language, connected by foreign key)?
2. how to select right language data after user selects locale? I'm not sure, that my method, where I check a locale variable every time, when I need to send data to view, is right.

I'm asking because I wonder how maintain and take care of my code.

Comment: One of the things I usually do is having an `app_strings` table, with fields: `string_key (indexed, unique), lang_id and text`. In the actual value tables, I only store the string_key. Depending on selected language, I fetch the appropriate text using a helper method. Ex: 
`{{ app_trans($product->name) }}` - here `$product->name` contains a string-key.

Comment: @techfoobar thank you, I'll try that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a middleware and add it to a group that will hold all the routes that require translation. In the middleware, you check the language from the session and set it so the current request can use it.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if( !Session::has('locale' )){
        $browserLanguage = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2); //read browser language

        if ( array_key_exists($browserLanguage, Config::get('languages')) ) {
            Session::set('locale', $browserLanguage);
        } else {
            Session::set('locale', 'en');
        }
    }

    //Simply set language from session 
    App::setlocale(Session::get('locale'));

    return $next($request);
}
```

When the user wants to select a specific language, you give them a list of available languages, then set the selected language into the session

```
if (array_key_exists($language, Config::get('languages'))) {
    Session::set('locale', $language);
}
```

As for the table, if you are sure you will only have 3 languages, then you can create a single table with 4 columns

```
key      en      fr       es
hi       hi      salut    ola
```

Comment: thank you, that's helps a lot!

Comment: You can also make a single table and use translation_key and locale as the primary key. That will allow you to have as many (or few) languages as you'd like.